# How to: remove Explorer tabs, add Search in Start, expand Start menu

Tags: windows-10

I have three customization inquires (Win10Pro x64 1909):

1.After removing the ribbon with RibbonDisabler some other options appear in the Explorer page.

They change from the type of folder, but they are like the ones below: Organize, System properties, etc.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Xw7w.jpg)

They seem to be related to right click context menus. I've tried removing Give access to that is present both in the top bar and the right click menu, but only the menu one was removed.

Removed the right click menu with this method:
https://www.thewindowsclub.com/remove-items-from-new-context-menu

On Win7 there seems to be a solution, but haven't found one for Win10:
https://www.sevenforums.com/customization/325520-remove-organize-include-library-new-folder-bar-windows-7-a.html

How can they be removed?

2.Upgraded recently from an older Win10 version, one that had Cortana in the Start menu.
I can add a search bar or a search icon in the taskbar, but can't add it to the Start menu. 
Can't Pin to Start.
Don't want Cortana necessarily, just Search, but in the Start menu.

Is this possible in 1909?

3.How to expand the Start menu horizontally to a custom size?
If I drag it to the right (menu is on the left), it snaps back to where the tiles are. Only if the horizontal dimension is double to that of the tiles does it stay. But then it's too large.
The tiles are expanded from Settings>Personalization>Start>Show more tiles on Start.

Thank you.

Comment: I cannot address all your requirements as I adapt to and use Windows 10 as it evolves.  1. Cortana and Search have been separated in V1909. Cortana is the round circle icon and Search is the magnifying icon. Different functions now.  2. The left hand start menu grows wide when using it and snaps back to thin menu when not using it.  So far as I can see Windows 10 is changing

Comment: How can either Cortana or Search be added to the Start menu? If I try to add more tiles horizontally, to the left, it does not let me. How can the menu be enlarged horizontally, by one or two tiles for example?

Comment: I don't think you can move Cortana or Search to the Start Menu. They are not menu items so no option to move them. Same with the Task View Button. These three cannot be unpinned from the Task Bar where as regular apps on the task bar can be unpinned. You can add Tiles to the Start menu in available space and then re-arrange. Left of the left tiles is not available space.